# How to select strings with the most keywords matches?

Tags: java, search, keyword

I'm trying to select top 3 strings which contains the most matches..
I'll explain it like this:
assume that we have the following keywords: "pc, programming, php, java"
and the following sentences:

```
    a[0]="what is java??"<br>
    a[1]="I love playing and programming on pc"<br>
    a[2]="I'm good at programming php and java"<br>
    a[3]="I'm programming php and java on my pc"<br>
```

so only the last 3 strings must be selected cause they are the top 3 strings containing the most matches.
How to do this in java???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dataset is small and you only care about exact matches, you could do something like the following:

Loop over each of your sentences performing an indexOf check for each keyword.  If this returns something that isn't -1 then increment a counter for that sentence.  Repeat for each keyword.  At the end find the 3 sentences that have the highest counter.

This approach will have all kinds of issues though including things such as:

- Case insensitivity
- Tags matching partial words, e.g. "java" matching "javascript"

Ideally you would use a full text engine like Lucene/Solr/ElasticSearch and let that do all the heavy lifting for you

Answer (score 1):

Arguably the easiest method would be to use Regex, an expression based system which searches for patterns within strings.

Pick up a website which teaches Regex. I suggest this one for starters.
http://regexone.com/

Afterwards, familiarize yourself with Java Regex. I suggest looking into capture groups.

I will not give you code to do this, because I believe there are many online examples you can look at, and it is in your best interest to learn how to do this by yourself.